# How to effectively query several tables to produce an excel STYLE report in a dataGrid

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, report

I'm creating a C#, windows form application, using an Access database as a back-end. I use datasets and table adapters to transfer info from Excel into the database, then pull the records I need from the database using winforms.

I retrieve information from several tables for a Monthly sales report. Each report selected by Store# from a combo box needs:

- The Product name as a row (from product table)
  There is a field in the product table
  called productAnalysis that is marked
  with a 1 if the product should be
  included in the analysis report.
- The Beginning (inventory) count
  (selected by a date picker box)
- The (Beginning dates, product
  purchase    prices)
- The qty of each item purchased. (So a
  sum of qty by product#/store/date
  from the transactions table)
- The Ending (inventory) count
  (selected by a date picker box)
- The Ending dates product purchase
  prices.

Inventory counts for each store are saved to one table with the date, store#, countNo, and product#. All stores are saved to the same table. Each purchase is stored in the transactions table with the date, the purchase price, the qty, store#, and product# (there are a few other fields also that are not relevant to this situation). I need a sum of the qty purchased and last purchase price from this table.

My problem comes in the shape of trying to get all this information into one query to produce a `DataGridView`.

I will calculate some fields from all this information. All the information I can find applies to using SQL Server and I haven't been able to get those examples to apply to my situation. I can separate this into chunks and do the queries separately but putting it all in one location is proving to be problematic for me. Some of the queries I have tried are below.

```
SELECT AnalysisItems.ProductName, 
       BeginningCount.CountNumber AS Beginning, 
       sum(Transactions.TransactionQty) AS SumOfTransactionQty, 
       EndingCount.CountNumber AS Ending
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN (((AnalysisItems 
INNER JOIN BeginningCount ON AnalysisItems.Pmid = BeginningCount.Pmid) 
INNER JOIN EndingCount ON BeginningCount.Pmid = EndingCount.Pmid) 
INNER JOIN Transactions ON EndingCount.Pmid = Transactions.Pmid) 
       ON (AnalysisItems.Pmid = Product.Pmid) AND (Product.Pmid = Transactions.Pmid)
WHERE (((Product.ProductAnalysis)=1))
GROUP BY AnalysisItems.ProductName, BeginningCount.CountNumber, 
         EndingCount.CountNumber;
```

This gets me closer but still has several entries for the same products. I just can't seem to wrap my mind around how to do this in access.

```
SELECT 
    AnalysisItems.ProductName,
    BeginningCount.CountNumber AS Beginning,
    Sum(Transactions.TransactionQty) AS SumOfTransactionQty,
    EndingCount.CountNumber AS Ending,
    EndingCount.StoreAccount
FROM Product 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        AnalysisItems 
           INNER JOIN BeginningCount ON 
               AnalysisItems.Pmid = BeginningCount.Pmid
           INNER JOIN EndingCount ON
               BeginningCount.Pmid = EndingCount.Pmid
           INNER JOIN Transactions ON
               EndingCount.Pmid = Transactions.Pmid
    ) ON 
             (Product.Pmid = AnalysisItems.Pmid) AND 
             (Product.Pmid = Transactions.Pmid)
WHERE (((Product.ProductAnalysis)=1))
GROUP BY 
     AnalysisItems.ProductName,
     BeginningCount.CountNumber,
     EndingCount.CountNumber,
     EndingCount.StoreAccount;
```

Comment: Ok So I've kept at it, since this application deadline is tomorrow. What I did was create two different dataSets using the same columns. With the use of two date picker combo boxes they will display different info. Then I tried to "merge" the data tables. The dataGridView is still only displaying one of the tables though. So I still have to figure that out. Then add my calculated data also.

Comment: `DataTable one = new beginningDataSet.BeginningCountDataTable();
DataTable two = new endingDataSet.EndingCountDataTable();

//Combine the dataTables into one.
            foreach (DataRow r2 in two.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn dc in two.Columns)
                {
                    one.Columns.Add(dc);
                }
            }
//I know these next two lines are not correct but I'm still trying to work it out. 
beginningDataSet.AcceptChanges();
dataGridView1.DataSource = beginningDataSet.Tables;

Answer (score 0):

Well there is probably a much easier way to do this but I can't seem to find it. I am a beginner though so one day I'll look back and think how easy it was I'm sure :) What I did was..

Put 3 DataGridView boxes onto a form. On screen load, I load the "Prior" months data into the first one and The currents months data into the second one. I have them minimized and locked behind the 3rd Grid so they can't be seen. Then I create a dataTable using each row from each of the first two grids. Perform what calculations I need to while and add all of it to the third table.

```
       private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //to load the first chosen months data
        this.beginningCountTableAdapter.Fill(this.beginningDataSet.BeginningCount, Convert.ToInt32(storeAccountComboBox.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text));
        //to load the second chosen months data
        this.endingCountTableAdapter.Fill(this.endingDataSet.EndingCount, Convert.ToInt32(storeAccountComboBox.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text));

        //Create new DataTable
        DataTable dtItems = new DataTable();

        //add columns to the dataTable
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Beginning", typeof(decimal));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Purchases", typeof(int));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Ending", typeof(decimal));
        //Add a new Column to Calculate the Value
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Total Gone (Usage)", typeof(decimal)); 
        //add more columns for $ value
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Beginning$", typeof(decimal));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Purchases$", typeof(decimal));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Ending$", typeof(decimal));
        //Add a new Column to Calculate the Value
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Total Gone ($)", typeof(decimal));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("% of Sales", typeof(decimal));

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                //first column
                string product = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

                //calculation for TotalGone (usage)
                decimal beginning = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                decimal purchases = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                decimal ending = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                decimal totalGone = ((beginning + purchases) - ending);
                //Variables for conversions for $ column math
                decimal beg = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                decimal begPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                decimal begValue = beg * begPrice;
                decimal pur = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                decimal purPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                decimal purValue = pur * purPrice; 
                decimal end = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                decimal endPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                decimal endValue = end * endPrice;
                decimal totalGoneValue = ((beg * begPrice) + (pur * purPrice)) - (end * endPrice);

                totalGoneColumnTotal = totalGoneColumnTotal + totalGoneValue; //The total of all product totalGoneValues
                decimal salesPercentage = 0; //The sales percentage
                thirtyPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(txtThirtyPct.Text); //the thirty percent discount txt entry
                double chickenValue = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[28].Cells[0].Value);
                chickenRebate = (chickenValue * .512);
                double steakValue = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[29].Cells[0].Value);
                steakRebate = steakValue * .550; 
                totalWithRebates = (Convert.ToDouble(totalWithDiscount) - ((chickenRebate + steakRebate)));
                try
                {
                    decimal sales = Convert.ToDecimal(textSales.Text); //convert the sales entry
                    salesPercentage = totalGoneValue / sales * 100; //find sales percentage
                    totalWithDiscount = totalGoneColumnTotal - thirtyPercent; //find thirtypercent discount amount
                }
                catch { MessageBox.Show("The sales entry must be a number between 1 and 999999.99");
                break;
                }

                //add colors to the output. 


                //Add rows to the DataTable
                dtItems.Rows.Add(product, beginning, purchases, ending, totalGone, begValue, purValue, endValue, totalGoneValue, salesPercentage);                
            }//end for

            //Totals Summary Rows
            dtItems.Rows.Add("Totals", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, totalGoneColumnTotal, null);
            dtItems.Rows.Add("30% discounts",  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, thirtyPercent ,null);
            dtItems.Rows.Add("Total w/discount", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, totalWithDiscount, null);
            dtItems.Rows.Add("Chicken Rebate x * 5.12", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, chickenRebate, null);
            dtItems.Rows.Add("Steak Rebate x * 5.50", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, steakRebate, null);
            dtItems.Rows.Add("Total w/Rebates", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, totalWithRebates, null);

            //Set the DataTable as DataSource of the GridView
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dtItems;
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Could not determine values. There may be no data for this date range/store."); }
```

Like I said, I'm sure that's probably a very wierd way of doing it, but I couldn't get anything to work using just the dataTables..